# when use group in the mongo, how can I get nested array in nested array size?

Tags: mongodb

here is collection

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5cc7d8e88c33e065c56b0883"),
   "age":70,
   "child":[  
         {  
            "id":"son1",
            "age":40,
            "grandSon":[  
               {  
                  "id":"grand1",
                  "age":10
                  "grandGrandSon" :[
                            {
                                "id":"grandGrand1",
                                "age":10
                            },

                            {
                               "id":"grandGrand2",
                                "age":13
                            }
                            ]
               },
               {  
                  "id":"grand2",
                  "age":13
                  "grandGrandSon" :[
                            {
                               "id":"grandGrand1",
                                "age":12
                            },

                            {
                               "id":"grandGrand2",
                                "age":14
                            }
                            ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":"son2",
            "age":40,
            "grandSon":[  
               {  
                  "id":"grand1",
                  "age":10
                  "grandGrandSon" :[
                            {
                               "id":"grandGrand1",
                               "age":15
                            },

                            {
                               "id":"grandGrand2",
                               "age":16
                            }
                            ]
               },
               {  
                  "id":"grand2",
                  "age":14
                  "grandGrandSon" :[
                             {
                                "id":"grandGrand1",
                                 "age":12
                             },

                             {
                                "id":"grandGrand2",
                                 "age":13
                             }
                             ]
               }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to result like this
parent age and child'size and grandSons Count, grandGrandSons count

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5cc7d8e88c33e065c56b0883"),
    "age": 70,
    "childCount": 2, 
    "grandSonsCount": 4
    "grandGrandSonsCount": 8, //important
    "grandSonsAgeCount": 105 // not important
}
```

here is my code

```
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "..."
        localField: "...",
        foreignField: "..",
        as: "child"
    },

},
{ $unwind: "$child" }
{ $group : {
    _id : "$_id",
    age: {$first:"$age"},

    childCount: {$sum: 1},
    grandSonsCount : {$sum : {$size : "$child.grandSon"}},

    grandGrandSonsCount : 
    {$sum : {$sum : {$size : "$child.grandSon.grandGrandSon"}}}, 
    //it is return 4(grandSonsCount)

}},
```

I used lookup, making for above collection(child)
I want to modify

`//{$sum : {$sum : {$size : "$child.grandSon.grandGrandSon"}}}`

it return grandSon count, but I want to get grandGrandSon Count

how can I get nested array in nested array of size?

I want to get grandGrandSon size

how can I have to do??

Comment: is your child an array or an object? Cause i think there is some mistake in your document. child is represented as an array but, it doesnt have curly brace for your object. it should either be an object, or an array of objects. An array cant have fields

Comment: wait I'm modifying sorry ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `unwind` your `child` array and `grandSon` array to be able to get the size of your `grandGrandsons` array.

Try this :

```
db.collection_name.aggregate[{
        $addFields : {
            childCount : {$size : "$child"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$child"
    },{
        $unwind : "$child.grandSon"
    },{
        $group :{
            _id : "$_id",
            age : {$first : "$age"},
            childCount : {$first : "$childCount"},
            grandSonsCount : {$sum : 1},
            grandGrandSonsCount : {$sum : {$size : "$child.grandSon.grandGrandSon"}},
            grandSonsAgeCount : {$sum : "$child.grandSon.age"},
            grandGrandSonAgeCount : {$sum : {$sum : "$child.grandSon.grandGrandSon.age"}}
        }
    }
]
```

Just adding childCount so that we don't face any issue calculating childCount after unwinding both the arrays.

Read more about [$unwind here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), and [$addFields here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/).

Comment: sorry ㅠㅠ, I modified it